# find percentage of sale and percentage of returns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in MS SQL DB which contains transactions of any company, there are two columns

1. `sub_cat_code`
2. `total_amount`

The `total_amount` contain sometimes positive and sometimes negative value. Where positive values indicates the **sale** and negative value indicates **Returns**.

Now, I need to find the percentage of sales and percentage of return using following query, in percentage of return column every value coming same. any help would be appreciable.

```
Select prod_subcat_code , 
(sum(total_amt)*100 /(select sum(total_amt) from transection)) as 
Sale_pers,
((select sum(total_amt) from transection where total_amt<0)*100/(select 
 sum(total_amt) from transection)) as return_sale
 from transection
 group by prod_subcat_code
 order by Sale_pers desc
```

Comment: sample data, expected results will help. What do you mean by "coming the same"?

Comment: Also, just as a note, it's spelt "trans**a**ction". Seeing as all your other column names use English, is seems you simply mispelt it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE which returns the total sales and total returns of the table:

```
with cte as (
  select 
    sum(case when total_amount > 0 then total_amount else 0 end) total_sales,
    sum(case when total_amount < 0 then total_amount else 0 end) total_returns
  from transection
)
select prod_subcat_code , 
  100.0 * sum(case when total_amount > 0 then total_amount else 0 end) / (select total_sales from cte) as sale_perc,
  100.0 * sum(case when total_amount < 0 then total_amount else 0 end) / (select total_returns from cte) as return_perc
from transection
group by prod_subcat_code
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f65a63f0666adec58aca159144461ee6).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you just want to divide two aggregated values:

```
Select prod_subcat_code,
       sum(total_amt) as net_sales,
       sum(case when total_amt > 0 then total_amt else 0 end) as sales,
       sum(case when total_amt < 0 then total_amt else 0 end) as returns,
       (sum(case when total_amt > 0 then total_amt else 0 end) /
        nullif(sum(total_amt), 0)
       ) as sales_ratio,
       (sum(case when total_amt < 0 then total_amt else 0 end) /
        nullif(sum(total_amt), 0)
       ) as return_ratio
from transection
group by prod_subcat_code;
```

Comment: Hii sir, i want to calculate percentage not the ratio.Like if total sale is 100% then i want to find how much percentage each sub category is contributing in total sale percentage.I hope,you got my point.

Comment: This is why I asked for sample data and expected results, @JatinGupta . We can't help you as easily when we don't know what your data looks like, nor what the end result you want is,

Answer (score 0):

You may want change your query to this for desired result:

```
Select  prod_subcat_code, 
        sum(case when total_amt > 0 then total_amt else 0 end) as sales,

        (sum(case when total_amt > 0 then total_amt else 0 end) /
        (sum(total_amt)) ) * 100 as sales_Percent,

        sum(case when total_amt < 0 then total_amt else 0 end) as [returns],

        (sum(case when total_amt < 0 then total_amt else 0 end) /
        (sum(total_amt)) ) * 100 as Return_Percent
 from transection
 group by prod_subcat_code
 order by sales_Percent desc
```

Answer (score 0):

*Hope it will help you,*

```
SELECT prod_subcat_code 
,(SUM(CASE WHEN total_amt > 0 THEN total_amt END)/sum(total_amt))*100 AS Sales_Percentage
,(SUM(CASE WHEN total_amt < 0 THEN total_amt END)/sum(total_amt))*100 AS Return_Percentage
 FROM transection
 GROUP BY prod_subcat_code;
```